# Comment addressed to multiple users with @?

Tags: support, comments

Can a comment be addressed to multiple users with the "at" sign (@)?

Comment: See the main resource: [How do comment @replies work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019/168244)

Comment: I changed the tag “feature-request” to “support” since it seems like you mostly wanted to know *if* this is possible and not to request *to make it possible*. Feel free to revert this and elaborate on your question if this assumption of mine was incorrect.

Comment: @doncherry Your tag change is sound.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it can't. Only the first user mentioned with `@`, and also the author of the commented post, will be notified. Note that the user must have been commented on the same post before.

An exception is the chat which works different. Here you can have multiple `@user` in one line. This works as long the mentioned users visited the particular chat room not too long ago.

Comment: What is "not too long ago"?

Comment: @LoverofStructure: I don't have any exact number. Personally I guess its either in the last days or in the last couple of hundred chat messages.